# Insert SVG into Component

Tags: svg, typescript, angular

I'm trying to insert an svg element (requested with http.get()) into an component 'icon'.

```
export class BgIcon {
  private svgSrc_: string;
  icon_: Icon;

  @Input('svg-src')
  set svgSrc(value: string) {
    this.svgSrc_ = value;
    this.icon_ = this.iconService.getIcon('cake.svg');
    this.adapter_.setInnerHTML(this.elementRef_.nativeElement, this.icon_.svg);
  }

  get svgSrc(): string {
    return this.svgSrc_;
  }

  constructor(private elementRef_: ElementRef,
    private renderer_: Renderer,
    public iconService: IconService,
    private adapter_: BrowserDomAdapter) {
  }
}
```

The IconService returns a cached object, with svg having the full svg-element as a string.
I can make the svg appear, with the above method. But I don't know if this is correct angular2'ish.

Are there any better ways to accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a better, more angular2'ish way. But I use the `@HostBinding()` for this. This results in something like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'bg-icon'
})
export class IconComponent {

    @Input() public svgSrc : string;

    @HostBinding('innerHtml') public svg : string = '';

    constructor(public iconService: IconService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.svg = this.iconService.getIcon(this.svgSrc).svg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Works perfect, this way. And I don't have to mess around with domadapters. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. You taught me about `BrowserDomAdapter`. I had not heard of it before :) Seems to come in handy as a last resource

Comment: I thought so too, about the last resource. I found that my code didn't feel right. Never thought that innerHtml could be bound to the host. it cleaned up my code quite a lot. Only one DI in my constructor now, instead of 3.